# How to avoid Python script name being regarded as namespace with Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

I am now making documentations with Doxygen for Python scrips. Suppose the name of the script is `all_the_best.py`, and at the beginning of the scripts, I document it as follows:

```
## 
# @namespace scripts.python
# This is a python script
import os
...
```

I suppose that the script will belong to scripts.python namespace in the Namespaces tab of generated HTML file. However, I found that in the Namespaces tab, not only scripts.python is available but also `all_the_best` appears. Any ideas on how to avoid it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things, and in my case I had to put EXTRACT_ALL = NO in the Doxyfile to have the second instance removed.